# hibernate query entity not by id

Tags: java, hibernate

I can query a row with the id with the following code:

```
Session session = (Session) HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
transaction = session.beginTransaction();

result = (T) session.get(clazz, id);
```

But i want to achieve something different.
Why isnt it possible (or is it?) to declare a certain column and get all rows which match this columns value. Like this:

```
Session session = (Session) HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
transaction = session.beginTransaction();

result = (T) session.get(clazz, "column", "column_value");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easily to implement with [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-creating) or [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

Suppose Hibernate doesn't support to get entities by not id column, because of [Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) patterns implementation with Hibernate L1 cache.

Also take into account differences between [Session#get and Session#load](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/) methods.